# cannot access org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPoolConfig class file for org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPoolConfig not found

Tags: java, maven, object-pooling, apache-commons-pool

I'm writing a daemon for getting servers stats for some game.

In compilation I've get a message:

> cannot access org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPoolConfig
> class file for org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPoolConfig not found

At this line of code:

[image: this]

[image]

Comment: You should post code when asking us to debug for you. Not just links (as they tend to rot away in time).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add the required libraries to the classpath for [`commons-pool`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-pool/) v2.0

> The Apache Commons Pool open source software library provides an object-pooling API and a number of object pool implementations. Version 2 of Apache Commons Pool contains a completely re-written pooling implementation compared to the 1.x series. In addition to performance and scalability improvements, version 2 includes robust instance tracking and pool monitoring.
>
> Version 2.7.x and up requires Java 8 or above.
> Version 2.6.x requires Java 7 or above.
> Version 2.5.x requires Java 7 or above.
> Version 2.0 requires 6 or above.

Comment: So, I've added it.

[link](http://images.gameru.net/image/direct/a5e2fa2456.png)

But it doesn't help anyway

Comment: Download from maven repository http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails|org.apache.commons|commons-pool2|2.2|jar